# When should the moderator election be?

Tags: discussion, election

**UPDATE:** [The election has been scheduled to start on September 26th](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/70), as per [the highest-scoring proposal here](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/190/70).

---

Since [enough people have expressed interest in running in the inaugural election](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/176/70), we have been discussing when the election should start in the [election chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138810/bioacoustics-election-discussion). We have been thinking of **starting the nomination period on September 26 (concluding  Oct 11), October 17 (concluding Nov 1), or later** and we still want to hear more people's opinions. Typically the nomination period will last one week, followed by voting for another week.

**Vote UP the answer post you agree with the date** (Vote DOWN only if you **strongly** disagree, and provide some reasoning for the disagreement if you can) or provide an alternative answer with a new date and why for others to vote for it.

You can also chat about it in the chat room linked above.

Click "FOLLOW" below this question if you want to receive a notification when a new answer is posted.

---

**Note:** Since elections in the Stack Exchange network always start on Mondays and conclude on Tuesdays, that puts some limitations on the dates we can choose from. Additionally, the date needs to account for potential holidays, as well as the general election calendar for the rest of the network, since CM oversight is required. Hence the proposed dates.

Comment: Considering it is already September, I do not know whether an October election is even possible. I have alerted the CM responsible for elections to keep an eye on this post in the next week, maybe they can share more about the possibilities.

Answer (score 9):

September 26 (concluding Oct 11)

Comment: +1 (I can't vote for my post)

Answer (score 2):

October 17 (concluding November 1)

Answer (score 1):

Second Oct 1!

We should maybe also do a separate Meta post as a final call for nominations?

**EDIT:** @JNat said that elections have to start on a Monday, so re-doing my answer for September 26!

Comment: Good idea. Let me ask in chat.

Comment: I think last we left in the chat yes, a meta post on nominations probably wouldn't hurt. One argument for waiting until the election's nomination phase starts is that it will ping all users and inform them about the election so that might attract more folks. But we could just refer to the existing call.

Comment: I'm fine with doing either!