# Inaugural Pro-Tempore Moderator election kicking off September 26!

Tags: discussion, election, announcements

**Summary**: Bioacoustics Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/election/3) on **September 26th** to pick your inaugural pro-tempore moderators.

Since it looks like there's [a consensus on when the inaugural election can open for nominations](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/190/70), I'm here to announce that it has officially been scheduled!

As a reminder, back in 2015, [we established](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/208518) that having active moderators was one of the only active requirements for keeping sites around in the Stack Exchange network:

> **If there's enough moderation for a public beta site to consistently remain free of spam, for flags to be cleared, and for our Code of Conduct to be upheld, your site will remain open.** However, if community leaders drop off, flags sit without being addressed, and we can’t find any suitable volunteers to step forward, the site gets closed.

**Without a successful first election that results in 3 users being appointed as moderators, the site will not be able to progress, and will instead be shut down.** As such, having a successful first election is a very important step for a budding community such as Bioacoustics.

Most of the details surrounding elections were explained previously, but as a reminder, here's what the timeline looks like.

### The timeline:

- Starting on September 26, users can nominate themselves on the [election page](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/election/3). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On October 3, if there are 4 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are 3 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (Bear in mind, users who have been suspended in the last year are not eligible to run and [may be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)

  - **If there are still fewer than 3 candidates at the end of the nomination period even after it is extended, the election will be considered a failure, and the site will be shut down.**
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on meta on October 11 (or October 18, if we need to extend the nomination period).

---

We recognize that the circumstances surrounding this election are uncommon, but I want to reiterate what I've said numerous times over the past weeks: there are many viable election candidates within this community who we hope will nominate themselves for the position — at least [4 of whom have expressed interest in doing so](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/176/70). **The Community Team is confident that this community can be healthy and thrive.**

**The success of this site rests on the outcome of that election, and at least 3 moderators are required for it to be considered a success — for that reason, we encourage anyone who is eligible to nominate for the position once the nominations are open.**

If you have any questions about the process, please ask them in an answer below.

Comment: The nomination period is only extended if we don't have 4 candidates right?

Comment: If you have _fewer than_ 4 candidates, to be precise, @Ethan.